# Rebuild Smart Group Cache - One of parameters (value: 28,55,57) is not of the type Int

Tags: smartgroups, cache

Running 5.47.1 at the moment on latest version of WP. I've been getting this error repeatedly:

Finished execution of Rebuild Smart Group Cache with result: Failure, Error message: One of parameters (value: 28,55,57) is not of the type Int

What do I do to resolve this issue? Asking as the most recent answers are from 2015.

Comment: Do you know which smart group is causing this?  If so, could you please edit the question to show a screenshot of the parameters of the smart group in question?  Also please comment if you don't know which smart group it is but can SSH into the server, I have a script that should make it clear.

Comment: I don't know which smart groups are causing this issue, your script would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that one of your smart groups is broken.

The low-tech approach to figuring out which is to disable half of your smart groups, run the "Rebuild Smart Group Cache" scheduled job (**Administer menu » System Settings » Scheduled Jobs**) and check its job log to see if the problem group is in the disabled half or enabled half.  Keep eliminating half the groups at a time until you've found the troublesome group.

Review its criteria (in **Contacts menu » Manage Groups**) and see if there's an obvious alternative (or if you even need the group anymore).

If you have more tech skills, you can download my [smart group profiling script](https://gist.github.com/MegaphoneJon/59089c1e155645a438af41051bca7ce7).  This requires you have [cv](https://github.com/civicrm/cv) installed.  Its original purpose is to find smart groups that are slow, but if you have a failure like the one you describe, it will fail on that group, and the last group listed is the one that failed.